# What do I need to do to change CellFrameStyle in the stylesheet?

Tags: stylesheet

My stylesheet inherits definitions from Core.nb.  I want the cell frame of a particular cell to be dotted.  I went to "Edit Stylesheet" and then selected the cell style I want to change.  I opened the options inspector and went to Cell Options->Cell Frame Options.  I made CellFrame to be True and a cell frame shows up. In CellFrameStyle I tried a variety of things but nothing seems to work.  The last thing I tried was:

{Directive[Dotted], Directive[Dotted], Directive[Dotted], Directive[Dotted]}

I tried a number of variations on this and nothing happens.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `Dashing[{0, Small}]` instead of `Dotted`, which is what `Dotted` evaluates to.

Comment: That worked.  Thank you!  I would upvote your comment if I could.